# Produce unicode obj from string in python?

Tags: python, unicode

```
test = unicode('\x03B', 'utf-16BE', 'ignore')
```

Produces gibberish. I would like test to be a semicolon. If I replace the hex with `'\x03~'` I get a semicolon.

My question is why? I thought the unicode value of semicolon was 003B ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one character that looks like a semicolon. Since you
mentioned `'\x03~'` and the utf-16be encoding, you must be referring to
the GREEK QUESTION MARK. (Below, I'll denote  `'\x03~'` as `b'\x03~'` to make this answer valid
in both Python2.7 and Python3.)

```
In [207]: b'\x03~'.decode('utf-16be')
Out[207]: u'\u037e'

In [208]: import unicodedata as UDAT

In [209]: UDAT.name(u'\u037e')
Out[209]: 'GREEK QUESTION MARK'

In [206]: u'\N{GREEK QUESTION MARK}' == u';'
Out[206]: True

In [198]: u'\N{GREEK QUESTION MARK}'.encode('utf-16be')
Out[198]: b'\x03~'
```

So, the unicode U+037E (GREEK QUESTION MARK), encoded in utf-16be is `b'\x03~'`, not `b'\x03'`.

---

Note that this is not the same as U+003B (SEMICOLON):

```
In [211]: u';'.encode('utf-16be')
Out[211]: b'\x00;'

In [212]: UDAT.name(u';')
Out[212]: 'SEMICOLON'

In [214]: hex(ord(u';'))
Out[214]: '0x3b'

In [216]: u'\u003b' == u'\N{SEMICOLON}'
Out[216]: True

In [217]: u'\N{GREEK QUESTION MARK}' == u'\N{SEMICOLON}'
Out[217]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

You failed to correctly specify the UTF-16-encoded semicolon, which consists of two octets, `\x00` and `\x3B`. The correct statement is:

```
test = unicode('\x00\x3B', 'utf-16BE', 'ignore')
```

This produces a Unicode semicolon, as expected.